# TreeSet comparator OR comparble.compareTo() priority

Tags: java, treeset

If the Java TreeSet is set with a comparator to deal with the objects sorting logic But the objects ( class) also implements comparable and have valid compareTo method implemented on it.

Which one takes priority? The logic within the comparator or the logic in the compareTo method?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Comparator passed-in to TreeSet's constructor takes priority. This allows for using a different comparison algorithm than is implemented by the object's `compareTo`. If it weren't for this, you'd never be able to use a different comparison algorithm with TreeSet.

Answer (score 4):

This is spelt out pretty clearly [in the Javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29) (emphasis added):

> `public TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)`
>   Constructs a new, empty tree set, **sorted according to the specified comparator**. ...
>
> Parameters:
>   `comparator` - the comparator that will be used to order this set.